# Why doesn't my computer work at full speed?

Tags: cpu, bios, overclocking

My motherboard is a Gigabyte GA-8I915PL-G with an Intel Pentium 4 630 3,0 GHz which doesn't run at it's default speed. It's currently at FSB 800, CPU Host 200 and CPU 3000 MHz; but sometimes it runs at FSB 533, CPU Host 133 and CPU 2025 MHz. Sometimes it's even at FSB 75 and CPU 1128 MHz.

When I configure the default settings in Easy Tune then my computer doesn't work. Sometimes I need to clear the CMOS so I can set the default settings in the BIOS, but that doesn't always help.

I've updated the BIOS, what else can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 6):

Are you sure it's not just saving energy?
Put some load with youtube HD videos and look if it doesn't speed up. CPU-Z will report the changes in real time. My core i5 goes from 1200 MHz to 2800 MHz every time it needs more speed.

Answer (score 6):

The [Pentium 4 630](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=27478) comes with [SpeedStep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpeedStep) which downclocks when the load is less to reduce power consumption/heat buildup.

> SpeedStep is a trademark for a series of dynamic frequency scaling technologies, including SpeedStep, SpeedStep II, and SpeedStep III built into some Intel microprocessors that allow the clock speed of the processor to be dynamically changed (to different P-states) by software. This allows the processor to meet the instantaneous performance needs of the operation being performed, while minimizing power draw and heat dissipation. Enhanced Intel SpeedStep is sometimes abbreviated as EIST.

This is the cause for the variations